# How can I smooth/deblock a video file with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, virtualdub

I am not interested in upscaling my video file, but am instead interested in just encoding it to smooth out the pixelation of my files. My files are from a T2i DSLR and I'd just like to smooth out the pixelation of the video in it. I did this with MSU Smart Deblocking, but MSU does not allow commercial usage and is copyrighted.

I am mainly interested in a 9,000 bitrate H.265 AMD GPU encoded .MKV video file with uncompressed PCM audio that is 1920x1080 like the original 1920x1080 using the Lanczos as deblocking.

The main thing I'd like to do is a simple lossless like video file compression with smoother looking less pixelated video than before.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You say first that the video is from a DSLR, then that it has been encoded on a AMD GPU: so this is not the original one, but an already reencoded one? Is the reencoding the reason of the pixelisation? ffmpeg has a deblock filter, I never used it but it would be something like `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v deblock=filter=weak:block=4 -map 0 -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -crf 20 output.mkv`. The documentation of the filter is here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deblock